# how to extract all child in firebase with certain part of the id iqual to some string

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

having  [this firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btNsa.png) how do i retrive only the childs of chats that child key have almost the current user id. 
the chats child id are like this **11-126**

so let say mi user id us 11. i want to retrive all child with all it data that have 11 in any side of  - . if there is a child with 89-11 o 253-11 o 11-254 i want to retrive all of those childrens. 
now i'm retriving all child and watching if key contains the id im interested whit this code.

```
chatsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] snapshot in
        if snapshot.key.contains(String(requestManager.instance.user.id!)){
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{
                let id = data["id"] as! String
                let name = data["name"] as! String
                let message = data["body"] as? String
                let senderId = data["senderId"] as! String
                let url = self?.rootRef.child("user").child(senderId).value(forKey: "url") as? String

            }
        }
    })
```

afer the conversion to Dictionary I got an error.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   optional value.

the data value is this.

[image]
seem to be that data["0"].value wourl work but it does not. Any idea how to extract all the values of the child added

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to retrieve all chats for user `11`, which means that either `senderId` or `recipientId` is `11`. This type of OR query is not possible with the Firebase Realtime Database, which only supports queries on a single property.

Instead, add a data structure to your JSON that holds the chat room IDs for each user ID. So:

```
"userChats": {
  "11": {
    "11-126": true
  } 
  "126": {
    "11-126": true
  }
}
```

With this additional data structure you can easily look up the chat rooms for a user under `/userChats/$uid` and then load the individual chat rooms for them.

Comment: thanks for the replay, but is not posible for me to change the data structured, i was not created for me, so i have to consume it to interact with an android app, that resolve the issues in very odd way. the thing is that i dont want to donload all chats child and then parse in swift to retrive wich match some user id, because is there is 50000 childs under chat that would be very expensive network op.

Comment: On NoSQL databases you commonly expand and modify your data model for the use-cases of your app. You need to implement a feature that the original database author didn't design the data model for. Hence: you will need to modify the database model to efficiently allow the new use-case. If you don't want to do that, your only way implement the use-case is to download all data. There is no third option that gives you what you want without changing/augmenting the data

Comment: For a good primer, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).