# Observable on one parent node vs multiple sub node Firebase angular 5

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5, observable

I have a confusion regarding `Firebase` `observable` in `angular`, here is structure

[image]

I want to watch all chats of particular user who logged in to my app, and I am seeing two option for achieve this.

1. Watch `/chats` `node` which means logged user will get notification for all `users` `chats` and I have to filter out logged `user` `chats`.
2. Watch multiple `node`  like `/chats/chatId` , `/chats/chatId` .... so on, In this logged `user` will not get notification for all `users` `chats`, It will only get their own `chats` notification.

So which one will be good or if something better than this Please let me know.

Comment: I would say, its better to listen to chat node, chat.author equals <userId>.

Comment: @rijin But It would be  bad for logged user to  get all events from other users chats in case of watching full node /chat.

Comment: you will be querying for a specific user, so how will you get all users messages?

Comment: @rijin I am taking about top-level `/chats` node not about `/user/id/chats` .

Comment: and as you can see in `users/id/chats` there is mapping of logged users chats userId=>chatId, so I have to watch all these chatId in top-level `/chats`.

Comment: Are you creating an app where multiple users can have chats with one person or many? ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/52218336/5675325 )